# css slideshow body text

Tags: html, css

This may be a trivial question but I'm currently having problems displaying the main> text of an HTML document below an ul> based Image Slideshow created following this [guide](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/comment-page-7/#comments). My intention is to have the Image Slideshow above the rest of the  content which once loaded can be scrolled down away to access the rest of the content. I've tried multiple div>s, flexbox, tables, positions and haven't been able to find an answer I'm happy with while searching SOF. Once loaded the page presents with the content and Image Slideshow overlaid with one another. This is my first project in HTML and CSS and was hoping to get a better foundation in both before jumping to more JS. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /* Set properties of navigation header */
    .nav {
      width: 100%;
      height: 3.0rem;
      position:fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      background:rgba(46,105,163,0.7);
    }
    /* Set navigation bar link color */
    nav a {color:#00FFAA;
      text-decoration:none;
    }
    /* Set navigation bar list center horizontal */
    nav li {
      float:left;
      font-size: 1.75em;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: .25em;
      padding-left:.35em;
      padding-right:.35em;
     color:#00FFAA;}
    
     nav li:hover{
       background-color: rgba(7,208,141,0.8);
     }
    
     #menu {
       float:left;
       font-size: 1.75em;
       padding:.25em;
       width: 2em;
       height: 2em;
       display:none;
     }
    
    /* Homepage Slideshow */
    
    
     .cb-slideshow,
     .cb-slideshow:after {
         position: absolute;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         top: 0px;
         left: 0px;
         z-index: 0;
     }
    
     .cb-slideshow:after {
        content: '';
    }
    
    .cb-slideshow li span {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        color: transparent;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        background-repeat: none;
        opacity: 0;
        z-index:0;
        animation: imageAnimation 12s linear infinite 0s;
    }
    
    .cb-slideshow li div {
        z-index: 1000;
        position: absolute;
        bottom:2em;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        opacity: 0;
        color: #fff;
        animation: titleAnimation 12s linear infinite 0s;
    }
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 {
        font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
        color: rgb(46,105,163);
        font-size: 7em;
        padding: 0;
        line-height:6em;
    }
    
    .cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span {
        background-image: url("/assets/home/lonely_island.jpg")
    }
    .cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
        background-image: url("/assets/home/iron_giant.jpg");
        animation-delay: 6s;
    }
    
    .cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div {
        animation-delay: 6s;
    }
    
    @keyframes imageAnimation {
        0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
        25% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
        50% { opacity: 1 }
        100% { opacity: 0 }
    }
    
    @keyframes titleAnimation {
        0% { opacity: 0 }
        25% { opacity: 1 }
        50% { opacity: 1 }
        52% { opacity: 0 }
        100% { opacity: 0 }
    }
    
    /*Slideshow end */
    
    
    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect
    html {
    background-image: url("/assets/home/lonely_island.jpg");
    min-height:100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    }
    */
    
    
     h1 {
       text-align: center;
       padding-top:2em;
      color:rgb(46,105,163);
      font-size:2em;
    }
    
    h3{
      padding-left: 2em;
      padding-right: 2em;
      padding-top:0.5em;
    }
    
    /*Paragraph Styling*/
    p {
      padding-left: 5em;
      padding-right: 5em;
      padding-top:1em;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-family:Calibri;
    }
    .nav {
    color: rgb(0,255,170);
    }
    /* Mobile site navigation */
    
    @media only screen and (max-width : 650px) {
    
    header {
    position:center,fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    }
    
    #menu {
      display:inline-block;
    }
    
    nav ul, nav:active ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background: rgba(46,105,163,0.7);
    top:3em;
    width: 7em;
    }
    
    body{
      z-index: 2000
    }
    nav:hover ul {
      display: block;
    }
    nav li {
      text-align: center;
      width:100%;
      padding:.25em;
      font-size: 1.5em;
    
    }
    
    /* Text styling for mobile layout */
    
    a:link {
        color: rgb(0,255,170);
        background-color: transparent;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:visited {
        color: rgb(0,255,170);
        background-color: transparent;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:hover {
        color: rgb(0,255,170);
        background-color: transparent;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    a:active {
        color: rgb(0,255,170);
        background-color: transparent;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    /*Paragraph Styling for mobile*/
    p {
      padding-left: 2em;
      padding-right: 2em;
      padding-top:0.5em;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family:Calibri;
    }
    h3 {
      padding-left: 2em;
      padding-right: 2em;
      padding-top:0.5em;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family:Calibri;
    }
    
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 {
        font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
        color: rgb(46,105,163);
        font-size: 5em;
        padding: 0;
        line-height:5.5em;
    }
```

```html
<header class="nav">
      <nav>
          <a id="menu">T^T</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/pages/home.html" id="home">T^T</a></li>
          <li><a href="/pages/about.html" id="about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="/pages/blog.html" id="blog">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="/pages/photos.html" id="photos">Photos</a></li>
          <li><a href="/pages/resume.pdf" id="resume">Resume</a></li>
          <li><a href="/pages/contact.html" id="contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    
    <main>
    
      <div class="cb-slideshow">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span>Image 01</span>
          <div>
            <h3>Welcome.</h3>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><span>Image 02</span>
        <div>
          <h3>Bonjour.</h3>
        </div></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
      <h1>Welcome.</h1>
        <h3></h3>
    
      <article class="blogP">
        <header>
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>description</p>
          <time class="publishedOn" datetime="2017-11-27">November 27, 2017</time>
          <a class="author" href="/pages/about.html">
            <p></p>
            <img src="/assets/about/auth.png">
          </a>
        </header>
        <a class="coverImage" href="#">
          <img src="/assets/blog/coverImages">
        </a>
        <p>Written article introduction</p>
      </article>
    
      <article class="album">
      
    <h3>
      <a href="#">Sample Album</a>
    </h3>
    <time class="publishedOn" datetime="2017-11-27">November 27, 2017</time>
    <a class="author" href="/pages/about.html">
      <img src="/assets/about/auth.png">
    </a>
    <a class="albumImage" href="#">
      <img src="/assets/photos/coverImages">
    </a>
    
      </article>
    </main>
    
    <footer>
      <ul class="social">
        <li>Facebook</li>
          <li>Twitter</li>
            <li>Instagram</li>
              <li>Flickr</li>
             </ul>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Try sending the link of the webpage which you have created.

Comment: I currently have it hosted on a local Apache server but have tried both that and Atom-Live-Server and get the same result.